# Does is break SRP to keep incompatible physical units and quantities together in the same class, where quantities describe an object?

Tags: object-oriented, solid, single-responsibility

I want to design a `Crate` object.  A crate is a wooden box that stores things.  I need to be able to keep track of of the following things in regards to this crate:

- length in inches
- width in inches
- height in inches
- weight in pounds
- price of crate in dollars

**My question**

can I store all of the above in the same class?
Does it break SRP if I store the quantities in the same class?

An alternative, for example will be to break up the class into 3:

- CrateDimensions (length, width, height)
- CrateWeight (weight)
- CratePrice (price)

My specific use case is as follows:  I have various many products that can be put into the crate.  Based on those products I have code that creates the crate - sets up initial dimensions and weight of the product inside the crate, and if more product is added, the crate dimensions are adjusted, as well as the weight.  Price is something that is not currently added, but will be added later.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  The class still has a single responsibility: *Crate.*  You might want to separate price out (because the crate's identity isn't the only thing that determines its price).

Comment: `if more product is added, the crate dimensions are adjusted` -- This is a *stretchy* crate?

Comment: If price is for **just the crate**, it could belong here.  If it includes the contents it should be elsewhere.  Of course, there are often bulk discounts, etc. that make all this messier.

Comment: I have dimension (in an Excel sheet) that show how big a crate is to be when it contains a pump product. On that Excel sheet there is an add-on to length dimension if the crate is to *also* contain a motor to go with the pump.  To deal with this I imagine to have an `addMotor` method that will effectively increase the crate dimensions. I am not sure how else to handle this.  I have to add the add-on number to the length in order to accommodate the crate for the motor, so mabe it has to be a stretchy crate object (?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your design, although as @RobertHarvey points out in the comments, you might want to treat price separately, as that can depend on a lot of things besides the crate itself. That's dependent on your business rules in regards to price, though.

Your `Crate` class does have one responsibility - describing a crate. Dimensions and weight are pretty integral for describing a physical object, especially when your use case seems to be to use it for containing objects of specified dimensions and weights. From what you've told us, it sounds like a pretty good class.

You might find that you want to extract the set of dimensions into a `Dimensions` class, which would contain properties for `Length`, `Width`, and `Height`. You could then add some methods / operator overloads to e.g., handle adding two `Dimension`s together, which I'm guessing you do as you pack items into the crate. Your `Crate` and `Product` classes could both use this `Dimension` class, making your arithmetic a bit less messy.

The use of a `Dimensions` class doesn't take away from the benefit of having the `Crate` class hold its own dimensions, whether its as a single property or 3 different ones.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you explain your last paragraph?  Are you saying it doesn't matter if `Crate` holds a `Dimension` class or if `Crate` holds three variables `length`, `width`, and `height` individually?

Comment: @Dennis Exactly. How you define the dimensions is irrelevant in deciding whether you should hold the dimensions at all.

Answer (score 4):

Up to now, you've only described attributes, no responsibilities at all. This isn't actually object-oriented, and the SRP isn't applicable. Start by looking at what you want to do in your application, and what roles the crate plays in it. Attributes come later as needed to fulfill these roles. If you find that the Crate object's only responsibility is to hold attribute values for some algorithms to work with, then that's its responsibility, and SRP isn't violated.

Comment: Excellent point. As described, the Crate is a property-bag, or structure, not a class (yet).

Comment: `Crate` seems more like a value object to me - to hold dimensions and weight.  There must be another class somewhere in my design with methods like `addProduct`.  `Product` can be pump, motor, etc that are part of my `Product` class.  I am thinking I will need another class to do operations of adding product to `Crate`.  I don't know if those operations can be part of the `Crate` object itself.